# Good ending for cross cultural sponser letter

Tags: correspondencia

I am sponsoring a child in Bolivia as part of a missionary outreach program. the child is a girl and is ten years old. What would a good closing be? This will be my first contact with the child and we do not know each other.

Comment: How would you state it in English? Perhaps we may start off from there.

Comment: I don't need help with the translation- I need help with the greeting itself. I read somewhere that in spanish countries endings are very sentimental, such as "hugs to you". Here in america,a typical ending is "sincerely" or "love". What would be normal to a spanish speaker?

Comment: It depends on the tone of your letter. We need more information; your question is pretty vague as is and it risks being closed. For example, do you feel the typical letter closings you can find on the Internet aren't suitable for you case, like the ones in [this page](http://www.blogdeespanol.com/2013/03/maneras-de-terminar-una-carta/)? If so, why? Are you expecting to see her soon? What is your relationship with her? Are there any more details you can provide?

Comment: Jeremy, welcome to the site. I agree that this question is pretty open. Also, I think that you may be overthinking this. I remember my English teachers stressing the importance of starting the letter with "Dear ..." and then the comma, finishing with "Your sincerely /faithfully", etc. Forget about all that. You are writing to a 10 year old. Don't constraint yourself with any kind of grammar/etiquete rules.

Answer (score 1):

If she's so young you could use a simple sentece like

> Espero que te vaya bien

*I hope you'll be ok*